# Update table with MAX() and MIN() from another table + performance problems

Tags: mysql, database, sql-update, max, min

I have a problem that i have tried to solve for the last 2 days, i have 2 tables, `workspat` and `xtractor_wrk`.
`xtractor_wrk` contains 250000 rows and `workspat` contains 67 million rows.

```
CREATE TABLE `xtractor_wrk` (
  `db_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `db_position` point NOT NULL,
 `db_namn` char(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
 `db_sis` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `db_om` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `db_seq` char(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `db_grarri` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `db_grtime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 KEY `db_time` (`db_time`),
 KEY `db_sis` (`db_sis`),
 KEY `db_om` (`db_om`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC

CREATE TABLE `workspat` (
 `db_time` datetime NOT NULL,
   `db_point` point NOT NULL,
 `db_om` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
 `db_sis` mediumint(8) NOT NULL,
 `db_status` char(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
 KEY `db_sis` (`db_sis`),
 KEY `db_om` (`db_om`),
 KEY `db_time` (`db_time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci
```

I have 2 problems:

What i would like to do is to update my table xtractor_wrk with the MAX(`workspat.db_time`)
and the MIN(`workspat.db_time`) from the result i would get from the "ON" below .

I have tried a lot of things but the only think i got somewhat working was this:

```
UPDATE xtractor_wrk 
JOIN workspat 
ON  date(xtractor_wrk.db_time) =    date(workspat.db_time) 
    and xtractor_wrk.db_om = workspat.db_om 
    and    xtractor_wrk.db_sis = workspat.db_sis 
SET xtractor_wrk.db_grtime =    workspat.db_time
```

and of course this does not give me the MAX and MIN update to `xtractor_wrk` its just that this 
is the only thing that even remotely worked for me.

workspat.db_time can have any number of matches and i would like the highest and lowest and write them to `xtractor_wrk.db_grtime` and `xtractor_wrk.db_grarri`

I also have a problem with speed, i have tried indexing but its still very slow, is there a way to index across tables or is my problem all the updates? Can i write the result to a new table instead of updating or maybe delay the update since its 250000 rows to update? How would i do that?

Comment: We need more information  "show create table table_name" outputs

Comment: I have added create table to my question

Answer (score 0):

Trying to suggest only

Add new column that indicates that is already updated or not like 1 if already updated and 0 if its not updated and also add where clause for more faster updating.

Example:

```
column 1 column 2 column 3 ... Updated
                                  0
                                  1
                                  0
                                  0
                                  1
```